# Training ResNet18 on Kaggle Cats and Dogs Dataset stuck on 0%

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm attempting to train a ResNet18 model on the Kaggle Cats and Dogs dataset (kagglecatsanddogs_5340/PetImages) but encounter an issue where the training doesn't proceed. Below is my setup and code. Despite the code execution starting, it halts at 0% progress without errors or further progress.

I've ensured that the dataset is correctly placed and accessible.

After initiating the training, the process stalls with the following output:

```
Total params: 11,689,512
Trainable params: 11,689,512
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.75
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 82.01
Params size (MB): 44.59
Estimated Total Size (MB): 127.35
----------------------------------------------------------------
Epoch 1/3
----------
  0%|          | 0/5015 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

I'm unsure of the cause of this issue. Could there be a problem with the data loading, or is there an error in how the model is set up or trained? Any assistance or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey @TAT, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide the code that you are running, your question only currently shows the output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.